# Python (3.4.2) How to plot a 2D array with a given radius as a circle?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, radius

```
  from matplotlib.pyplot import *
```

For example I have a 2D Array, stored under the variable name: 'R':

```
 ([[ 0.680979  ,  0.8126483 ],
   [ 0.4634487 ,  0.14742914],
   [ 0.27596818,  0.70073533],
   [ 0.52843694,  0.54878972],
   [ 0.13926434,  0.4223568 ],
   [ 0.39956441,  0.31257942],
   [ 0.06566612,  0.65883135],
   [ 0.44879016,  0.33009628],
   [ 0.68340944,  0.67422729],
   [ 0.25075741,  0.08038742]])
```

I want to plot a circle of radius r at the following coordinates, for example disk 1:

```
x-coordinate: 0.680979 y-coordinate:0.8126483
```

I would like all the circles to be plotted on 1 graph.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify the size of the circle in *screen* units use `scatter`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X, Y = np.array ([[ 0.680979  ,  0.8126483 ],
   [ 0.4634487 ,  0.14742914],
   [ 0.27596818,  0.70073533],
   [ 0.52843694,  0.54878972],
   [ 0.13926434,  0.4223568 ],
   [ 0.39956441,  0.31257942],
   [ 0.06566612,  0.65883135],
   [ 0.44879016,  0.33009628],
   [ 0.68340944,  0.67422729],
   [ 0.25075741,  0.08038742]]).T

r = 10  # in units of sq pixels

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc = ax.scatter(X, Y, s=r)
```

[`scatter` docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter)

if you want to set the size in *data* units:

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.collections as mcoll
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
circles = [mpatches.Circle((x, y), radius=.1) for x, y in zip(X, Y)]
coll = mcoll.PatchCollection(circles)
ax.add_collection(coll)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
# you may have to set the x and y limits your self.
ax.set_xlim(...)
ax.set_ylim(...)
```

[`circle` doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Circle), [`PatchCollection` doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection)

Comment: I received an error as 

               fig, ax = plt.subplots()
               NameError: name 'plt' is not defined